# Fields required to specify a video in source / citation

Tags: sources, citation

Is there a ready guide on fields to complete for source data if the source is a video? What are the fields we should be completing for a video source?

Comment: It depends. What citation scheme have you already adopted?

Comment: I just am not sure - are you able to steer me in the right direction on both of these?

Answer (score 1):

The most common citation format in genealogy is based on Chicago style which offers [video](https://libguides.csuchico.edu/c.php?g=414275&p=2823091), [online video](https://libguides.csuchico.edu/c.php?g=414275&p=2823092), [film/television](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/chicago_manual_17th_edition/cmos_formatting_and_style_guide/audiovisual_recordings_and_other_multimedia.html), [audiovisual](https://research.wou.edu/c.php?g=551307&p=3785492) [materials](https://research.wou.edu/c.php?g=551307&p=3785499) etc. But generally it has been adapted specifically for genealogical sources by [Elizabeth Shown Mills in Evidence Explained](https://www.evidenceexplained.com/). I don't have ready access to Mills' book, but it appears to have different fields based on the source of the video. A similar style is Turabian for [video](https://libguides.nwmissouri.edu/turabian/media). Some of the fields include: Presenter, Narrator, Creator, Performer, Host, Correspondent, Director, Filmographer, Clip ID, Show Title, Segment Title, Series Title, Format, Publisher city, Producer, Publication/Production Company, Copyright date, Broadcast Date, Release Year, Network, Source, Collection, Where Held, Medium, Runtime, URL, Access Date depending on what kind of video it is, what information is on it, and where it is from.